# Why does this match type employing object types equate to Nothing?

Tags: scala, scala-3, match-types

In Dean Wampler's book, [Programming Scala, 3rd Edition](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-scala-3rd/9781492077886/), there is an [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jpRVDziCQbydad1GkDZ5XA) with:

```
type Elem[X] = X match
  case String => Char
  case IterableOnce[t] => t
  case Array[t] => t
  case ? => X 

summon[Elem[List[Int]] =:= Int]
summon[Elem[Nil.type] =:= Nothing]
```

It doesn't seem to be explained, at least in the surrounding context, why `summon[Elem[Nil.type] =:= Nothing]` and not `summon[Elem[Nil.type] =:= Nil.type]`. Why is this the case?

Comment: `case IterableOnce[t] => t`

Comment: Ah, right, I had forgotten None extends `Option[Nothing]`, for instance, and `Nil` extends `List[Nothing]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `Nil` extends `List[Nothing]`, thus your `case IterableOnce[t] => t` applies and `Elem[Nil.type] =:= Nothing`.